# Why does PostgreSQL have to be different (scheme does not exist)?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm not used to working with PostgreSQL, but am using Zend_Db_Select to create my queries.
What does the error below mean?

```
SQL error:
ERROR:  schema "il" does not exist

In statement:
SELECT il.count(*) AS "count" FROM "image_lite" AS "il" 
INNER JOIN "exif_parse" AS "ex" ON il.image_id = ex.image_id 
WHERE (ex.cam_make = 'apple')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's parsing `il.count(*)` as a call to a function "count" in the schema "il".  Probably what you want is the expression:

```
count(il.*)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can think of schema in PostgreSQL as you would a database in MySQL. Also try removing the double quotes around everything because that's just plain strange and might be causing the problem.

Oh I see il.count(*) make no sense at all.

Just do this instead:

```
select count(*) cnt       
  from image_lite il 
  join exif_parse ex on il.image_id = ex.image_id 
 where ex.cam_make = 'apple'
```

Comment: +1 for removing the double-quotes.  That irritates me just as much when people backtick the heck out of everything in a MySQL statement... probably where the bad habit came from!

Comment: The quotes are automatically inserted by the Zend_Db_Select

Comment: quotes can lead to unexpected behaviours in postgresql if identifiers are not lowercase (not your case but anyway). Khorkrak gives the correct sane syntax

Answer (score 1):

Postgres is interpreting the "`il`" in "`il.count(*)`" as a schema name.  You can simply omit it and ask for `count(*)`, or if you want to get specific, `count(il.*)`

If you're coming from MySQL, schemas are what the rest of the world calls what MySQL calls a database.